# how can I install vundle to my neovim in powershell

Tags: powershell, neovim, vundle

I'm using **powershell neovim**, and I want to **install a plugin named auto-pairs to my neovim**,

I tried to edit the _vimrc and ~/vimfile but it doesn't work at all.

then I found my neovim file in ~/AppData/Local/nvim and nvim-data, here's their structure :

[nvim](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1yr3.png),[nvim-data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44k4j.png)

it seems to be there isn't a file named bundle, so I don't know where to put the vunle.vim and how to configure it

please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well I've resolved it
by adding Plug 'jiangmiao/auto-pairs' to my init.vim.

By using vim-plug, it can be installed